# Why is a json result displaying NaN for one property?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, nan

Maybe the title is not specific. Anyways, I'm working on a search feature. After the controller sends me back a Json object with all the data I need, and after I try to put them in a table row, one property (description property) is constantly displaying NaN.
I tried to convert it, "put" the value in a independent variable, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the proof the json object received from is OK.

[inspect element - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcIZY.png)

Thank you!

```
$.ajax({

            method:"get",
            data: data,
            url: url + "?companyId=" + companyId +"&barCode="+ data

        }).success(function (response) {
            var table = $('#binderTable');
            var tBody = table.children('tbody');
            tBody.html("");
            var textbox = document.getElementById("searchBar");
            textbox.value = "";

                tBody.append(
                "<tr><td>" +response.BarCode + "</td><td>" +
                           +response.Description + "</td><td>" +
                           +response.Year + "</td><td>" +
                           +"</td></tr>"
                );

            table.removeClass("hidden");
            var originalTable = $('#originalTable');
            originalTable.remove();

        }).error(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: basic debugging: `console.log(response)`. make sure that the `NaN` isn't literal text embedded in the response body to begin with.

Comment: can you show your response string that you receive? and which part of the  code you are using it?

Comment: I figured it out. The + sign converted the output into a number, but it's not a number.  Thank you guys anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the + operator which coerces data into a number. For example, 
    typeof +"4" === "number" // true

You are trying to coerce the string of response.Description into a number, but the + operator on letters will result in NaN. Take out one of the + operators immediately before response.Description and you should be good to go!

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!!!